# How to print all one level child elements except one from the xml

Tags: xslt

To print all the child elements from the xml except one.

```
<Store>
<Store Name>Store name</Store Name>
<Store address>Store address</Store address>
    <book>
    <name>book name</name>
    <description>very good fiction</description>
    <price>300</price>
    <pages>540</pages>
    </book>
</Store>
```

I will get the value in pa ram parameter="Store/book"

I need to print as below:

book name 300 540
I dont want to fetch the description, How do I do it using XSL

Comment: FWIW, XSLT does not "print", it creates a result tree, which you can then serialize. If you want to print it, you'll need another program to do that for you, though most processors offer the possibility to write the output to `stdout` (which may be what you mean with "print").

Answer (score 1):

To select all child elements except `description`, do:

```
select="*[not(self::description)]"
```

In XSLT 2.0 you can do:

```
select="* except description"
```

Comment: Or, if you use the copy idiom as a starting point, you can add a matching template like `<xsl:template match="description" />` to get rid of it :).